# Ruby: Including raw HTML in a Nokogiri HTML builder

Tags: html, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm writing code to convert a [fixed XML schema](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/bindings/xml/comment-xml-schema.rng) to HTML. I'm trying to use Nokogiri, and it works for most tags, e.g.:

```
# doc is the Nokogiri html builder, text_inline is a TextInlineContent node
def consume_inline_content?(doc, text_inline)
  text = text_inline.text
  case text_inline.name
  when 'text'
    doc.text text
  when 'emphasized'
    doc.em {
      doc.text text
    }
  # ... and so on ...
  end
end
```

The problem is, this schema also includes a `rawHTML` text node. Here is some of my input:

```
<rawHTML><![CDATA[<h2>]]></rawHTML>
Stuff
<rawHTML><![CDATA[</h2>]]></rawHTML>
```

which should ideally be rendered as `<h2>Stuff</h2>`. But when I try the "obvious" thing:

```
...
when 'rawHTML'
  doc << text
...
```

Nokogiri produces `<h2></h2>Stuff`. It seems to be "fixing" the unbalanced open tag before I have a chance to insert its contents or closing tag.

I recognize that I'm asking about a feature that could produce malformed html, and maybe the builder doesn't want to allow that. Is there a right way to handle this situation?